# Import image from assets folder with root relative path, React Native Expo CLI project

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an React Native app created by Expo CLI (version 4.0.17).

I want to import Static Image Resources to app and follow this document: https://docs.expo.io/versions/v36.0.0/react-native/images/

But when the app larger, the path to import can be too long, like this:

```
import myImage from "../../../assets/images/myImage.jpg";
```

**How to import by root relative path like this?**

```
import myImage from "assets/images/myImage.jpg";
```

I try to config `babel.config.js` like this, but it's not working:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true)
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: [
      [
        "module-resolver",
        {
          alias: {
            assets: "./assets",
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  }
}
```

But I can import like this, and it's work:

```
import myImage from "static/images/myImage.jpg";
```

**So what is `static` here, and it's safe to import like above?** I can't find it in any document.

Answer (score -1):

Yep, it's safe to import images like this. This will make your code look cleaner and easy to understand.

Comment: Do you know what document which `static` path is mentioned? I'm afraid it will change in the future.